# Can't boot to arch linux after installation (dual-boot with Windows 10)

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, grub

For the past few days I have been trying to install arch linux but have not succeeded in doing so. The installation goes completely fine but when I restart the computer I don't get GRUB and it doesn't even appear in boot options.

I have done tons of research but I haven't found a solution that worked. I am not sure if this is the root of the problem, but in /boot/efi/EFI there is no arch folder after doing grub-install and grub-mkconfig (there was an ubuntu folder when I had ubuntu).

I am pretty sure fstab is correctly configured. I followed all the steps in the arch guide and I have no idea what could have gone wrong.

Edit: secure boot is disabled and it boots directly into Windows. If I make the boot menu appear (pressing F12), I only get the windows option. The output of efibootmgr -v is the following:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 2001,0001,2002,2003
Boot0000* USB HDD: USB     Flash Disk   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(0,0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x72539,0x800,0xf00000)RC  
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,88f77a3e-99ca-42d8-9191-96d66428a9f6,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0002* GRUB  HD(1,GPT,88f77a3e-99ca-42d8-9191-96d66428a9f6,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi)
Boot0004* arch  HD(1,GPT,88f77a3e-99ca-42d8-9191-96d66428a9f6,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\arch\grubx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

Comment: Does it boot straight to windows? have you disabled secure boot ?

Comment: @vfbsilva yes to both questions

Comment: I had a similarly problem with Linux Mint 18.2 and have succes with this tutorial.
https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: Major Windows updates seem to mess with UEFI boot variables sometimes. In Windows, start a command prompt *as administrator*, then run this command: `bcdedit /enum firmware` The result should be a long listing, does it mention GRUB anywhere? Or in Linux, you can get an equivalent listing in much more compact form with `efibootmgr -v`.

Comment: @telcoM I just added the output of efibootmgr -v to the question

Comment: Generally speaking if an entry is in NVRAM such as `Boot0002 GRUB \EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi` but it does not show up in the boot menu its because the EFI application is inaccessible. Note that it is not in BootOrder. Further RC which enables the entry for Boot Display Services (the boot menu) is not indicated for the missing entries.

You should try to provide even more information like the model number. I will say from experience issues like this point to buggy UEFI firmware.

Answer (score 1):

The `efibootmgr` output indicates the first non-USB boot item listed in BootOrder is 0001, which corresponds to `Boot0001` line - which is the Windows bootloader. So Windows 10 has just promoted itself to the top of the list, as it sometimes does during major updates.

First, identify your EFI System Partition using the UUID listed in the `efibootmgr` output:

```
# blkid | grep 8f77a3e-99ca-42d8-9191-96d66428a9f6
```

This should identify the Linux device (probably something like `/dev/sd*`) corresponding to the actual ESP used by the firmware. Make sure it is mounted at `/boot/efi`; some Linux distributions actually leave it unmounted by default.

Then verify that either `/boot/efi/EFI/GRUB/grubx64.efi` or `/boot/efi/EFI/arch/grubx64.efi` exists.

If neither of those actually exists, run `grub-install <disk device reported by blkid>`: that should fix it.

If either of those `grubx64.efi` files exists, you can add Linux back to the boot order with:

```
# efibootmgr -o 2001,0002,0004,0001,2002,2003
```

(This corresponds to "try first an UEFI boot from a USB HDD, then `\EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi` from the ESP partition, then `\EFI\arch\grubx64.efi` from the ESP partition, then fall back to Windows bootloader and the DVD and network boot options.")

Typically the last step would be the only thing you'll need after a major Windows update, but if something has actually caused the ESP partition contents to be completely rewritten, you may need the `grub-install` step too.

Comment: I did that and now I get "Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)". I  did some research on this  error but nont of the suggested fixes seems to work for me. Also, it seems weird that the option that boots to arch is under the title "Windows Boot Manager"

Comment: That indicates the kernel is not able to access the root filesystem. Either the GRUB configuration file does not include the correct boot options (missing `root=/dev/something` boot option most likely), or the initrd/initramfs file does not include the right kernel module(s) to access the disk containing the root filesystem.

Comment: I don't think it is the first one because the UUID is correct in /boot/grub/grub.cfg. How would I fix the second thing you mentioned?

Comment: GRUB needs two filesystems specified - first the filesystem that contains the GRUB modules (typically /boot), and second the root filesystem identifier that will be passed on to the kernel to be booted. These may or may not refer to the same partition/filesystem, depending on your partitioning choices. In Arch, the command to rebuild the initramfs file is `mkinitcpio`; unfortunately I'm not too familiar with it.

Answer (score -1):

I know it is my own question but I solved it and decided to add the answer in case anyone else comes across this problem.

I reset my PC following Microsoft's instructions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options%20). Then, I erased the linux home and root partitions to do a fresh install. In the process I had to mount the EFI system partition on /boot/efi and I realised that even after resetting the PC /boot/efi/EFI/GRUB and /boot/efi/EFI/arch still existed. I erased those directories in case they were corrupt and that was the problem in my previous attempts.

The install had no problems whatsoever but Windows still wouldn't let me boot to arch so I had to run from the windows cmd the following as administrator

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi
```

I was then able to boot into arch from the boot menu (pressing f12 at startup).

I still don't know what the exact problem was. If anyone could explain it please add an answer.